# How to add a column of repeated numbers in SAS?

Tags: sas

How to generate a repeating series of numbers in a column in SAS, from 1 to x?

Suppose x is 3.

Data is like:

```
name age 
A 15 
D 16 
C 21 
B 35 
E 79 
F 85 
G 64
```

and I want to add a column named list, like this:

```
name age list 
A 15 1 
D 16 2 
C 21 3 
B 35 1 
E 79 2 
F 85 3 
G 64 1
```

Comment: Who is `person3` in your sample data, and how do we know whether they are at work or not?

Comment: It's like we have 8 people and need to assign work to these guys, and if some of them are not at work today, they are on a vacation or sick days, we need to assign the work to the rest people. Here I use 3 people just to make it easier.

Answer (score 2):

```
data class;
   set sashelp.class;
   if list>=3 then list=0;
   list+1;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I can think of is to use `mod` and the iteration counter.

```
data want;
  set have;
  list = 1 + mod(_N_ - 1,3);
run;
```

`mod` is the modulo function (gives the remainder after dividing).

So if you want that to vary based on some parameter, well, change the 3 to a parameter.

```
%let num_atwork = 2;

data want;
  set have;
  list = 1 + mod(_N_ - 1, &num_atwork.);
run;
```

Comment: Love this idea! Thanks a lot!